# Hosting Nodejs RESTful web service using ssl certificate

Tags: node.js, rest, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have developed a RESTful web service using Node.js. I want to host this service on my home PC which is having static IP(which can be access from internet). But I want to host this service using SSL. Note that my home PC is not associated with any internet domain. So I want to know how to host my Webservice using ssl on my home PC. Also I want to know where to buy ssl certificate and what type of certificate? Because most of the certificate authorities who sells certificate talking about ssl for website only.

Comment: You can get a free certificate at https://letsencrypt.org. I'm not sure if it will work without any internet domain, though.

Comment: I second what Patrick says. Lets Encrypt is great. And it *will not* work without an domain. But domains are dirt cheap. It is possible to setup certs for IP's but not with Let's encrypt, and even then it's not a common practice and I'd advice against it.